# Integral of dependent uniform RVs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Help please,
If I have a:
$X\sim U[0,a]$ s.t. $a>0$ 
$Y|X=x\sim U[0,x]$ then:
$$f_Y (y)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx = \int_{0}^{a} f_{Y|X}(y)\cdot f_X(x)dx=\int_{0}^{a} \frac{1}{ax} dx = \frac{1}{a}(ln(a)-ln(0))$$

 Is there a way to get around this $ln(0)$? 

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the correct integral is
$$f_Y(y) = \int_y^a \frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{a}\,dx = 
\frac{1}{a}\log\frac{a}{y}.$$

Comment: Shouldn't the limits be for every x?

Comment: No, since $Y$ will be a uniform distribution over the interval $(0,X)$, $X$ is is bounded below by $y$.

Comment: ohhhh! thanks!!

Comment: No problem. Getting the correct bounds can be difficult. Zero couldn't have been a lower bound since you will have $\log 0$.